# Shopify Debut Theme Adding padding-bottom: 60px after page loads to the html element

Tags: javascript, css, shopify, shopify-template

For some reason after the page loads a style attribute is being added to the HTML element with `padding-bottom: 60px;`

How do I get it so this attribute is not added to the HTML element when the page loads. This is frustrating because I am not able to remove it using CSS.

I noticed other people have run into this issue and I tried copying one of the solutions which were to add this code to theme.js

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $('html').removeAttr('style');

});
```

Comment: Might be added by any 3rd party code when you logged into the backend and visit the website, can you try the same without login onto the backend into the new private window?

Comment: yeah, it doesn't happen when I'm not logged in. I tried on a different browser and it doesn't add the padding.

Comment: okay, so might be this due to some 3rd party code that is appended by any iframe or APP, and it adds the padding, you can use the CSS with important to avoid. the same, if you want really hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my testing this only happens when previewing a theme and Shopify inserts an `iframe` element at the bottom of the body (it has an id of `preview-bar-iframe`).

It's 60px high and a script adds some padding to the bottom of the `html` element. I guess to allow you to see all the page.

I use this script to remove the preview and padding after a couple of seconds.

```
// Remove the annoying Shopify #preview-bar-iframe
window.setTimeout(() => {
    let previewBar = document.getElementById('preview-bar-iframe')
    if (previewBar) {
        previewBar.style['display'] = 'none';
        document.documentElement.removeAttribute('style');
    }
}, 2000);
```